# Why is the "active" action value in palette of Material UI affecting the icons?

Tags: material-ui, themes

Trying out the theme in Material UI and came across something I didn't expected.

When trying out the different palette options in palette > action, the "active" value affected the icons inside of a "List", why is that?

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-theme-props-forked-gcp66?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

The style is applied to the `ListItemIcon` wrapper, see [source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/ListItemIcon/ListItemIcon.js#L11).

Comment: yes I do understand that but why would the action "active" color style apply to the "ListItemIcon"? Feels really wierd and I can't really understand why this decision has been made?